# Angular checklist-model undefined?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="checkbox m-b-15" ng-repeat="list in chkArray.riskForHospitalization" >
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="M1033"  data-checklist-model="pi.risHost" data-checklist-value="list.value">
         <i class="input-helper"></i>
         {[{list.title}]}
  </label>
```

I want to get the value of the selected checked item but when i submit the data model pi.risHost is undefined

Comment: post the code of the controller

Comment: What does this line `{[{list.title}]}` mean?

Comment: @cezar just to display the title i use  $interpolateProvider to change  {{ to {[{ because it conflict with phalcon

Answer (score 0):

Since your `checkbox` is inside ng-repeat, all the checkboxes inside the `ng-repeat` has same model. so use an array of models.

```
<div class="checkbox m-b-15" ng-repeat="list in chkArray.riskForHospitalization" >
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="M1033"
           data-checklist-model="pi.risHost[$index]"
           data-checklist-value="list.value">
    <i class="input-helper"></i>
    {[{list.title}]}
</label>
```

Here `pi.risHost` is an array of model and if you `checked` the **2nd** checkbox. then **`pi.risHost[1]`** will be true. and so on

Comment: it doesn't working haha.. so i come up with my final option which is to create an object array  in my controller which is where i can store the selected checkbox